# Where can I ask some "how to" questions about vintage Macs?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I've gotten some inexpensive 'vintage' Mac hardware I'd like to get running. A Mac Pro (desktop) and a Mac SE (Toaster, no drive) for $25 each. Neither runs fully.

I have questions about which OS, added hardware using on a network. Plus questions about the rack mounted Macs as well as Airport Routers. But before I get into the nitty I wanted to make sure this is the appropriate place ?

Comment: And there is a site focused on older and lower end Macs here: https://lowendmac.com

Answer (score 2):

> I have questions about which OS, added hardware using on a network. Plus questions about the rack mounted Macs as well as Airport Routers. But before I get into the nitty I wanted to make sure this is the appropriate place ?

You've come to the right place.  This site is an excellent site for vintage questions, especially since it's Apple specific.  We have some fantastic members who have been using Mac computers since the classic days.  I personally have experience with rack mounted Macs - Xserve - both PPC and Intel based.

[Retro Computing on Stack Exchange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) is also an excellent source, though they are quite broad and cover everything from PCs to Macs and even Commodore.

Comment: Retro computing is even broader than that. It includes mainframes vaxes minis and anything back to zuse and probably babbage

Comment: @mmmmmm, Retrocomputing's got tags for both the Difference Engine and the Analytical Engine.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to read through the help and tour.

Asking practical questions about Apple services and hardware meets our main criteria.

- https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/help

Just be sure to show your research and ask questions that are objective / scoped narrowly and things should work out very well.